# add group index value to groups

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe ('df') something like (simplified for this example):

```
index |     timestamp    | value
================================
001   | 2020-09-20 07:00 | 1.4
002   | 2020-09-20 07:00 | 1.5
001   | 2020-09-20 09:00 | 1.6
002   | 2020-09-20 09:00 | 1.4
001   | 2020-09-20 11:00 | 1.23
002   | 2020-09-20 11:00 | 1.46
```

If I do this:
`grouped = df.groupby('timestamp')`
I now have a groupby with three groups. I need to now add a 'date_time_trigger' column that contains a value based on the index of the group:

```
index |     timestamp    | value | date_time_trigger
================================================
001   | 2020-09-20 07:00 | 1.4   | triggergroup1
002   | 2020-09-20 07:00 | 1.5   | triggergroup1
001   | 2020-09-20 09:00 | 1.6   | triggergroup2
002   | 2020-09-20 09:00 | 1.4   | triggergroup2
001   | 2020-09-20 11:00 | 1.23  | triggergroup3
002   | 2020-09-20 11:00 | 1.46  | triggergroup3
```

I then need to combine the groups back into the original dataframe. I've tried simply adding column to the original data frame, then changing its value inside a group iterator:

```
idx=0
df['date_time_trigger']='foo'
grouped = df.groupby('timestamp')
for name,group in grouped:
  idx=idx+1
  group['date_time_trigger']='triggergroup'+str(idx)
```

And as far as I can tell, the value of `date_time_trigger` is being set inside each group, but now
I need to recombine the group into the original dataframe df to continue with my process. The only way I can find in the docs is to apply some type of aggregation, like mean or avg, but I just needed the groupby to add the labels to each group  instance. How do I get my dataframe back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check with `factorize`

```
df['group'] = df['timestamp'].factorize()[0]+1
```

Method two

```
df.groupby('timestamp').ngroup().add(1).astype(str).radd('triggergroup')

0    triggergroup1
1    triggergroup1
2    triggergroup2
3    triggergroup2
4    triggergroup3
5    triggergroup3
dtype: object
```

Comment: nice! could the output of factorize be concat-ed to a string, to give something like 'triggergroup3' as in my original question? I tried simple python string concat but pandas didn't like that

Comment: @regretoverflow check the 2nd method :-)